# How can I create a checkpoint file of a TensorFlow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to implement Neural Style Transfer using TensorFlow and want to integrate the same within an Android application for image filtering. Can anyone help me save this TensorFlow model, so I can restore it whenever in use in the application?

I've tried creating .ckpt file of this TensorFlow model, but I'm not able to create one.

I haven't copied the code here as it consists of dozens of lines. Here is the link for the model https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/nst_blogpost/4_Neural_Style_Transfer_with_Eager_Execution.ipynb

I am expecting to save this model to generate a new image at very low latency. Currently, I've to run hundreds of iterations for every image and that's what I don't want in real time while running in the application.